# How do I fix Ajaxterm connection error for text login after updating webmin?

Tags: webmin

I performed all the recommended updates listed in webmin and now when I click on text login I get the following.

"Ajaxterm did not start accepting connections on port 10001 after 30 seconds."

This did not happen before updating.
What is this and how do I fix it?

```
HP DL360 G6

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Webmin Version: 1.972
```

Comment: What OS & release are you asking about?   Have you tried updating it via terminal (warnings and errors would be easier to detect & thus correct there I'd suspect)

Comment: I get the same error, also updated webmin to 1.972. Looks like we need to file a bug report at webmin,

Comment: Bug report submitted.

Comment: [See here](https://sourceforge.net/p/webadmin/bugs/5463/). Do you have Python2 installed?

Comment: The issue corrected it's self. We noticed an update notification for webmin but when we went to update it the update was gone and the issue was gone. We can now access text login. I examined the logs but no update was performed and our scheduled updates are disabled. The only explanation I have is maybe a forced update from the webmin team.